# Angular 2 animations for smoothly vertical opening and closing block

Tags: css, angular, css-animations

In my angular 2 app I have component with static head and toggled container. I would like to add smooth animation for opening and closing content block, but can't find suitable transformations.
Now I tried to use this animations:

```
trigger('expandableState', [
      transition(':enter', [
        style({ transform: 'translateY(100%)', opacity: 0 }),
        animate('500ms', style({ transform: 'translateY(0)', opacity: 1 })),
      ]),
      transition(':leave', [
        style({ transform: 'translateY(0)', opacity: 1, display: 'none' }),
        animate('500ms', style({ transform: 'translateY(100%)', opacity: 0 })),
      ]),
    ])
```

but it moves content instead of component's border. Here is example in [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/9Q9FsOgZLk86hbQA3Fy0?p=preview). 
So, what styles should I use for smooth toggling content?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
animations: [
trigger('expandableState', [
  transition(':enter', [
    style({ height: '0', opacity: 0 }),
    animate('500ms', style({ height: '*', opacity: 1 })),
  ]),
  transition(':leave', [
    style({ height: '*', opacity: 1 }),
    animate('500ms', style({ height: '0', opacity: 0 })),
  ]),
])
]
```

I know that height isn't GPU supported, but i think it's the only option here.